# Shared Library issues when running over SSH (linux)

Tags: linux, ssh

I am having some difficulty running jobs over SSH.  I have a series of networked machines which all have access to the same Home folder (when my executable is installed).  While working on one machine I would like to be able run my code through ssh using the following sort of command:

```
ssh -q ExecutableDir/MyExecutable InputDir/MyInput
```

If I ssh in to any of the machines I wish to run the job on remotely and simply run:

```
ExecutableDir/MyExecutable InputDir/MyInput
```

It runs without fail, however when I run through SSH I get an error saying some shared libraries can't be found.  Has anyone come across this sort of thing before?

Comment: why did you tag this Batch-file?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, I'll rm it

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a programming question. could move to superuser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I figured it out myself.
It seems when you run things through ssh in the way shown above you don't inherit the path variables etc. that you would if you ssh-ed in 'properly'.  You can see this by running:

```
ssh RemoteMachine printenv
```

and comparing the output to what you would normally get if you were connected to the remote machine.  The solution I then went for was to run something like the following:

```
ssh -q ExecutableDir/MyExecutable source ~/.bash_profile && InputDir/MyInput
```

Which then gets all the paths and stuff you might need from the bash_profile file on the remote machine